# php - edit $name values to $name2

Tags: php, rename

Already asked but question was closed so here it is again:
I need to understand the code that renames values.

For example, I have $name which outputs 'A Long Way From Home', in case the script encounter this value I need to rename the value to 'LongWay34' into $name2 so I can use it somewhere else.

There's no need for any uber-script, I have just a few elements I need to modify and I can write a line for each one!

I hope I've been clear, thanks in advance for the help!
k

Comment: You want a PHP script to parse another PHP script, and rename all of the variables which match a specific string? That's no job for a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($name === 'A Long Way From Home') $name2 = 'LongWay34';
```

...?

Comment: This is what I was thinking too. Just an if statement

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing like *rename* in PHP.

There are **variables**, and you can assign a **value** to them.

Variables can hold data. To put data into variable you **assign** something to it. Examples:

```
$variable1 = "text value";
$variable2 = 24; //number value
$variable3 = $othervariable; // assign value of one variable to another (like "copy")
```

**You can't rename variable.** You can create new variable with diffrent name and assign old variable value to the new one.

```
$new_variable = $old_variable;
```

If I understand you correctly - you want code, that will run when variable value will become "some value". Normal variable don't have any "trigger" features, that will trigger some code. You have to check value of that variable and make conditional blocks (`if` for example).

There are special "variable" types, that can monitor changes of variable, run some additional code when variables are accessed. They are called `classes`, but now this may be too complicated for you to understand.

Comment: I think it's worth noting if you must save memory or otherwise must not copy the value, you can do something similar to renaming using variable variables. E.g. `$new_variable = 'old_variable'; some_method($$new_variable)`. However, this is harder to read and follow logically, so Kamil's solution is almost always better.